# Regex to match string with or without capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying for a while and not sure what to Google but I want both of these to be matched

```
Someone does something
```

and

```
Someone tries to do something
```

What I thought would work is

```
/^Someone (tries to)? do(es)? something$/
```

But that only matches the second string.

They are separate strings, not a single string spanning multiple lines.

Comment: If you strip out the optional tokens at a minimum your string needs to be `Someone  do something`.  Notice the double spaces

Comment: `/Someone (?:does|tries to do) something/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
/^Someone(?: tries to)? do(?:es)? something$/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/XvT9rt/1)

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Someone                  'Someone'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     tries to                ' tries to'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   do                      ' do'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    es                       'es'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   something               ' something'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```